# Creating a grid of adjacent squares of the same side length in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

[Grid of patches in adjacent squares of equal side length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FwZk.png)Is there code for implementing a grid of squares (of patches) in NetLogo? Each square must be directly adjacent to and aligned with its neighboring squares and all squares must have the same length of side (like graphing paper). The functionality to control or vary the side lengths of the squares would be ideal ...

Below, I believe is a sample code for generating this grid but with random, undefined edges:

```
to generate-habitats [ habitat-spots ]
  let habitat-ID 0
  ask n-of habitat-spots patches [
    set pcolor item habitat-ID base-colors
    set habitat-ID habitat-ID + 1
  ]
  while [ any? patches with [ pcolor = black ] ] [
    ask patches with [ pcolor != black ] [
      ask neighbors with [ pcolor = black ] [ set pcolor [ pcolor ] of myself ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

But I would like for the edges to be straight and adjacent to each other in aligned square configurations as opposed to random and jagged.

Comment: You should try doing this yourself first. If you run into a problem you can't fix while trying, feel free to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) **about that specific problem**.

Comment: First of all, do you realize that you can change the number and size of patches?  Do you really need patch clusters, or is this just a display issue?

Comment: @Alan Thank you for your response. I do realize that I can change the size of patches but I am looking for more of square blocks with patches contained within. I am thinking of it as a square mesh with each square containing about an equal number of patches in the netlogo world, regardless of how the patches are sized (square bins of patches). Ideally, I would like to be able to vary the side length of the squares (and therefore the number of squares) ...

Comment: @nigus21 What do you want to do with left-over patches?  Or did you want your setup to `resize-world` based on model parameters?
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#resize-world

Comment: each patch has coordinates px-cor and py-cor, why don't you construct a function using those coordinates (perhaps with modulo or floor primitives) to assign a habitat number to each patch?

Comment: @JenB That was going to be my last trick to make it work. Thank you for affirming the plausibility of that thought. I did think that there was some more intuitive netlogo call for doing it, but thanks!

Comment: @Alan I thought    resize-world    only lets me change the dimensions of the world in general with a new patch grid to match as an automated process. I am thinking more along the lines of demarcating a group of patches by equal-sized squares of some variable side-length (x). The grid "function" helps with that but the squares are not large enough to touch each other. Anyway, if there is no such solution, I shall go with the recommendation offered two comments above. Thank you all!